# Product Filtering PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello guys I'm doing a product filtering and I don't know how could I achieve it.
I used Javascript by getting the value of the selected values then alert it 
 but the problem is that how could I display it also how can I remove the categories selected by clicking the x button. Here the sample page.
 
 Thank you very much for your help.

[image: Product Filter]

Here is my script code:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#filter").val()
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery( ".product-line" ).each(function( index ) {
            var url = '<?php echo $upload_url; ?>';
            var desc_id = jQuery(this).eq(0).find('.prod-desc').attr('id');

          if(desc_id){
            var file_url =  url + desc_id + '/description.html';
            jQuery('#'+desc_id).eq(0).load( file_url );
          }

        });

        jQuery("#brand,#screen_size,#cpu,#memory,#price").change(function() {
          var brand = jQuery("#brand").val();
             var screen_size = jQuery("#screen_size").val();
             var cpu = jQuery("#cpu").val();
             var memory = jQuery("#memory").val();
             var price = jQuery("#price").val();
             var categories =[];
             if(brand)
             {
                categories.push(brand);
             }
             if(screen_size)
             {
                categories.push(screen_size);
             }
             if(cpu)
             {
                categories.push(cpu);
             }
             if(memory)
             {
                categories.push(memory);
             }
             if(price)
             {
                categories.push(price);
             }
             length = categories.length;
             categories2 = categories.toString();
             alert(categories2);
             var categories3="";
             for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                categories3 += "<div class='filter_style'>"+categories[i]+"<span style='margin-left:15px;color:gray;'>x</span></div>";
                jQuery("#filter").html(categories3);

            }
      });       
    });

</script>
```

My HTML Code:

```
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <select class="form-control product-type" id="brand" >
              <option value="">Select a Brand</option>
              <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
              <option value="Acer">Acer</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <select class="form-control product-type" id="screen_size" style="margin-top:0px;">
              <option value="">Select a Screen Size</option>
              <option value="Small">Small</option>
              <option value="Large">Large</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <select class="form-control product-type" id="cpu">
              <option value="">Select a CPU</option>
              <option value="Intel">Intel</option>
              <option value="Amd">Amd</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <select class="form-control product-type" id="memory">
              <option value="">Select a Memory</option>
              <option value="500mb">500mb</option>
              <option value="1tb">1tb</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <select class="form-control product-type" id="price">
              <option value="">Filter by Price</option>
              <option value="10000">10000</option>
              <option value="20000">20000</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This screams server-side processing to me. Get the user's input, send that to your server via ajax, return only the products matching the passed parameters, display those. If you insist on doing it client side, we'll need to know a good deal more about your HTML which you havent showed us at all....

Comment: where is x button?

Comment: @Fiido93 I updated the code. I already displayed it, the only problem right now is how can I remove the category once x button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibilities, I will **UPDATE** the answer if it wasn't correct.

But first can you help what will you get after you run this code?

```
jQuery("#brand,#screen_size").change(function() {     
    var brand = jQuery("#brand").val();
    var screen_size = jQuery("#screen_size").val();
    console.log(brand);
    console.log(screen_size);
});
```

Comment: I updated the code. I already displayed it, the only problem right now is how can I remove the category once x button is clicked.